# launching java with UseShellExecute

Tags: c#, java, windows, batch-file

Having some trouble finding out why some can run my application which is a minecraft launcher, it creates a .bat file and runs it using UseShellExecute. Not sure if its because of UAC crap or whatever.

For me I can put the exe in any folder and it will work, like could it be that it needs to be in the programfiles? I haven't made any installer for it.

It can use system java or portable java the program adjusts the folder paths etc... then creates the bat file with program settings.. then runs it after the file has been made.... like

```
Process Launchit = new Process();

     try
        {
            Launchit.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Launchit.StartInfo.FileName = exePath + "\\Launcher.bat";
            Launchit.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Launchit.Start();
        }
    catch (Exception exx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exx.Message);
        }
```

In Launcher.bat  something like this as an example...

```
"java" -Xms524M -Xmx1000M -jar "blahblah.jar"
```

It works for me, but for some it does nothing.. even if they try run the .bat file it doesn't work ie just opens and closes, trying to find out why is problematic. They do have java installed.

is there some way i could open cmd.exe have it goto the directory of the bat file and run it, just so they can see what the error is in the command console?

Comment: Why not have those users open cmd and copy/paste the content of the batfile in there to see the error?

Answer (score 0):

Run `cmd.exe` with the `/K` parameter and your batch file path as an argument. Check `cmd.exe /?` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

omg.. so the problem all along was that my launcher wasn't encapsulating "" the folder paths.. so some people who putting the exe in a folder that had spaces in it would have trouble running it, and others who put it in folder with no spaces it worked fine.

So didn't have to do that cmd.exe thing, though was going to.